# PHP MySQL undefined Index and other errors

Tags: php, mysql

having trouble getting a script of mine to run correctly, I have 2 undefined index errors and an invalid argument supplied error that for the life of me I can't figure out why I'm getting. the 2 undefined index errors come from these lines.

```
if(!is_null($_GET['order']) && $_GET['order'] != 'courseTitle')
```

and

```
if (!is_null($_GET['page']))
```

and my invalid argument error is this

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in

generated from this

```
<?php foreach ($books as $book) : ?>
```

my full code between the two classes is this.. any ideas of what I've done wrong? tearing my hair out over this.

```
index.php 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Catalog</title>
    </head>
    <body bgcolor="white">
        <?php
            /////////////////////////////////////////////////
            //connect to db
            /////////////////////////////////////////////////
            $dsn = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=book_catalog';
            $username = "php";
            $password = "php";
            $db = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password);

            //get data
            if(!is_null($_GET['order']) && $_GET['order'] != 'courseTitle')
            {
                $thesort = $_GET['order'];
                $query = "Select * FROM book
                INNER JOIN course
                ON book.course = course.courseID
                ORDER BY ".$_GET['order'];
            }
            else
            {
                $thesort = "courseTitle";
                $query = "Select * FROM book
                INNER JOIN course
                ON book.course = course.courseID
                ORDER BY $thesort";
            }

            //if page is null go to first page otherwise query for correct page
            if (!is_null($_GET['page']))
            {
                $query = $query." LIMIT ".($_GET['page']*8-8).", 8";
            }
            else
            {
                $query = $query." LIMIT 0, 8";
            }

            //query result
            $books = $db->query($query);

            //get number of overall rows
            $query2 = $db->query("SELECT * FROM book");
            $count = $db->query("SELECT Count(*) As 'totalRecords' FROM book");
            $count = $count->fetch();
            $count = $count['totalRecords'];
        ?>

        <table border =" 1">
            <tr>
                <th bgcolor="#6495ed"><a href="?order=course">Course #</th>
                <th bgcolor="#6495ed"><a href="?order=courseTitle">Course Title</th>
                <th bgcolor="#6495ed"><a href="?order=bookTitle">Book Title</th>
                <th bgcolor="#6495ed"></th>
                <th bgcolor="#6495ed"><a href="?order=price">Price</th>
            </tr>
            <?php foreach ($books as $book) : ?>
            <tr>
                <td><a href="rsc/catalog.pdf"><?php echo $book['course']; ?></a></td>
                <td><?php echo $book['courseTitle']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $book['bookTitle']; ?></td>
                <td><?php
                $bookcourse = $book['course'];
                $isbn = $book['isbn13'];
                $booklink = "<a href=\"course.php?course=$bookcourse&isbn=$isbn\">";
                echo $booklink ;?><img src='images/<?php echo $book['isbn13'].'.jpg'; ?>'></a></td>
                <td><?php echo $book['price']; ?></td>
            </tr>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
            </tr>
        </table>
         <?php
         //paging function... not sure if it works correctly?
            for ($j=1; $j <= ceil($count/8); $j++)
            { ?>

            <a href=<?php echo "?page=".$j."&order=".$thesort; ?>><?php echo $j; ?></a>
            <?php
            }?>
    </body>
</html>


**course.php**

<?php

    //get data from index.php
    $course = $_GET['course'];
    $isbn = $_GET['isbn'];    

        //connect to db
        $dsn = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=book_catalog';
        $username = "php";
        $password = "php";
        $db = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password);

        //get data
        $query = "Select * FROM book, course, author, publisher
    WHERE book.isbn13 = $isbn AND book.course = '$course' AND book.course = course.courseID AND book.bookID = author.bookID AND book.publisher = publisher.publisherID
            ORDER BY book.bookID";

        //query results        
        $books = $db->query($query);

        //error troubleshooting
          if (!$books) {
            echo "Could not successfully run query ($query) from DB: " . mysql_error();
            exit;
          }


        //count the number of rows in the result
        $results = $books->fetchAll();
        $rowCount = count($book);

        //get data from results
        foreach($results as $book){
            $bookID = $book['bookID'];
            $bookTitle = $book['bookTitle'];
            $isbn = $book['isbn13'];
            $price = $book['price']; 
            $desc = $book['description'];
            $publisher = $book['publisher'];
            $courseTitle = $book['courseTitle'];
            $courseID = $book['courseID'];
            $credits = $book['credit'];
            $edition = $book['edition'];
            $publishDate = $book['publishDate'];
            $length = $book['length'];
            $firstName = $book['firstName'];
            $lastName = $book['lastName'];

        }

        if($numrows > 1)
            {
                foreach ($books as $book)
                {
                    $authorArray[] = $book['firstName'] + ' ' + $book['lastName'];
                }
            }





?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>CIS Department Book Catalog</title>
    </head>
    <body bgcolor=white">

        <table border="0">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <img src='images/<?php echo $isbn.'.jpg'; ?>'>
                </td>
                <td>
         <?php
         echo "For Course: $courseID  $courseTitle ($credits)";
         echo "</br>";    
         echo "Book Title: $bookTitle";
         echo "</br>";    
         echo "Price: $price";
         echo "</br>";    
         echo "Author";
         if ($numResults > 1)
         {
             echo "s:";
             for ($i = 0; $i < $numResults; $i++)
             {
                 if ($i!=0)
                 echo ", $authorArray[i]";
                 else
                     echo $authorArrat[i];
             }
         }
         else
             echo ": $firstName, $lastName";

         echo "</br>";    
         echo "Publisher: $publisher";
         echo "</br>";    
         echo "Edition: $edition ($publishDate)";
         echo "</br>";    
         echo "Length: $length pages";
         echo "</br>";    
         echo "ISBN-13: $isbn";
         ?>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <?php echo "Description: $desc"; ?>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>

    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: What you are doing is terribly insecure.  You're already using PDO, so it isn't difficult for you to start using prepared queries.  As it stands right now, you are **wide open** to SQL injection attacks, and you **will be hacked** if you haven't been already.

Comment: why are you using !is_null instead of isset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You should be using `isset` not `is_null` to keep it from warning about undefined variables.
2. <strike>`$books` is never defined</strike> It was defined, just incorrectly ... `foreach` needs it to be an array. You really don't need it anyway, fetch each row into the array with a `while` loop. (see my example below). You're also redefining `$count` several times in your query.

And like @Brad said. Use prepared statements and placeholders. Your database will end up hacked with your current code.

**EDIT**

Answer to your question. `query()` returns a *statement handle*. (I've defined it as `$sth`). `fetch()` returns a *result* which you need to pass one of the fetch mode constants (or define it by default earlier with `$db->setFetchMode()`)

To get the books you need to have

```
$books = array();
$sth = $db->query($query);
while( $row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
    $books[] = $row; // appends each row to the array
}
```

Here's how your code should look to get a count.

```
// you're not using the $query2 you defined ... just remove it
$sth = $db->query("SELECT Count(*) As 'totalRecords' FROM book");
$result = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$count = $result['totalRecords'];
```

Take a look at:
http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers Looks like a good guide to give you an in-depth understanding of how to use PDO. Pay special attention to error handling and to prepared statements!

Comment: Hey thanks for the feedback I changed it to 'isset' in the code. As for your second part, I defined '$books' at this line, '$books = $db->query($query);' In case its hard to find in the code its right before the redefining counts. Am I missing something about the returns? Is it not already in array format?

Comment: Edited my answer extensively

Comment: Hey Cfreak, sorry to bug you, hopefully this is the last time, but I'm getting an error "Call to undefined method PDO::fetch()" on the PDO's you suggested. I made the changes to the code for count and books. As far as I can tell PDO::FETCH_ASSOC is a constant, and fetch() is defined? Is there something I need to call earlier in my code to implement fetch() correctly?

Comment: My bad. should have been `$sth->fetch()` I just did it wrong. I edited the answer to correct it